# Google oAuth domain issue with our SaaS multitenant webapi

Tags: google-oauth

We received this google warning because one of our google projects has multiple domains.

> Your project: {app} has multiple unique domains in the redirect URI and origin URLs, many of which have unrelated applications. This is in direct violation of the Google API Services: User Data Policy, which requires that projects accurately represent their identity and intent to Google and to our users when they request access to Google user data.

- The first domain is the website of the app {app}.tld
- The second domain is the api where OAuth happens {tenant-id}.subdomain.domain.tld

Our violation comes from the domain {tenant-id}.subdomain.domain.tld which is where we host our multi-tenant api.

Is it possible to resolve this issue while still using our multi-tenant api to handle the OAuth dance?

Comment: Hi, may I asked how you resolved this issue? Our application has same approach and we are struggling with the verification process.  We have app web on different domain then the api. And the api is multitenant as yours.  Are you now clear about what is the issue? Url following this pattern {tenant-id}.domain.tld? Or app web sitting on different domain? Or both? Here is by the way my post covering the app home page part {tenant-id}.subdomain.domain.tld

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are using the {tenant-id}.subdomain.domain.tld as the callback url and adding a unique url for each tenant.

To solve this issue i think you may add a single callback url. Something like callback.domain.tld may work. This endpoint should redirect the original google redirection to {tenant-id}.subdomain.domain.tld with all the query params from google. You can encode the tid in state so that you can decode it to redirect the request properly in the redirection service.

You can also use some services like AWS lambda to act as the middleman and redirect to your final endpoint.

Comment: This might technically work. But you probably also need a proxy server for replacement of header with origin. You are also listing javascript origins in google console. And I think this might work from technicall point of view but it would be probably in conflict with Goolge terms and conditions (masking app identity ...).

Answer (score 0):

It's okay with that {tenant-id}.subdomain.domain.tld as the callback URL and adding a unique URL for each tenant.